# Change only one plotmarker in listplot

Tags: plotting

If you have multiple data sets in one Listplot. Is it possible to change the plotmarker for only one data set? I basically want to keep the default plotmarkers for data sets I do not specify. I would have hoped that

```
ListPlot[{data1,data2,data3},PlotMarkers->{Automatic,Automatic,"*"}]
```

would work but it just uses the word Automatic as a plotmarker for the first two sets.

---

In version 12 the exact functionality I want is implemented with the exact syntax I expected above. I still could use a work around for version 11.

Comment: This works for me in Mathematica 12:
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Automatic, "*"}]

Comment: Thanks @banone. You are right. It seems they added exactly the functionality I wanted in version 12. That's nice. I still could use a work around for version 11. (On 11.3 and I guess earlier your example does not work and has the behaviour I described in the question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{data1, data2, data3} = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}} *)
```

With `Automatic` you get

```
ListPlot[{data1, data2, data3}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To use `Automatic` for all but one use `Show`

```
Show[
 ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic],
 ListPlot[data3, PlotMarkers -> Style["*", 20, Red]],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

> ***"I still could use a work around for version 11."***

As work-around for v11, you can: (1) use `PlotMarkers -> Automatic`, (2) correct the styling of markers using the function `fixMarkers`, (3) replace the marker for dataset `i` with the desired `marker` using the function `replaceMarker[i, marker]`:

```
ClearAll[fixMarkers, replaceMarker]
fixMarkers = Replace[#, {dir_, GeometricTransformation[Inset[a_, b__], c__]} :> {dir, 
  GeometricTransformation[
    Inset[Replace[a, _EdgeForm :> Sequence[EdgeForm[], dir], All], b], c]}, All] &;

replaceMarker[i_, marker_] := Replace[fixMarkers @ #, 
    p : {{___, _GeometricTransformation} .., ___} :>  
     MapAt[# /. Inset[a_, b__] :> Inset[marker, b] &, p, {i}] , All] &;
```

***Example:***

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}} ;
lp = ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large];

Row[{lp, replaceMarker[3, Style["*", 24]] @ lp}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]